# Codeigniter - Active Record How To Where(codition OR condition )

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where("Password",$password);
$this->db->where("Status",true);
$this->db->where("(Username = '$username' OR Email = '$email')");
$query=$this->db->get();
```

The query is successful for email condition but fails for username, can someone help me understand why this does not function the way it is expected.

Functionality : The query should return record when password=password and status=true and (username=username or email=email).

This is a login form where user can specify username and password or email and password and ay of these match the query should return the result.

Also on the other note the query does not match the password exactly i mean it is not case sensitive, i want the password comparison to be case sensitive so we can get a exact match.

Please help! Thanks i advbance

Answer (score 1):

As it is said in the user guide provided by CodeIgniter

If you use multiple function calls they will be chained together with AND between them:

```
$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->where('title', $title);
$this->db->where('status', $status);
```

The code above will generate the SQL as following:

```
WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'
```

And if you want to use OR in condition, you should try this:

```
$this->db->where('name !=', $name);
$this->db->or_where('id >', $id);
```

And the code above produces:

```
WHERE name != 'Joe' OR id > 50
```

Also you can execute SQL statement as following:

```
$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

In order to prevent SQL injection, you can do as following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?"; 
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired results by using the following. Here what we are going to do is first validate the user input that is it a email or username. If it is a username then check in username or if email check in usernames column.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where("Password",$password);
$this->db->where("Status",true);

$pattern = "(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)";

if(preg_match($pattern,$email))//check if entered value in email field is email
$this->db->where('email',$email);

else   // you can verify here username if it is any standard format
$this->db->where('username',$email);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

this query is much efficient as it saves the execution time of sql query.